# Connect to home router on secure port?

Tags: router, home-networking

I want to connect to my home LAN router externally. I have a domain set up that points to my public IP. When I browse to the FQDN, it connects to my router like I want, but only on HTTP. I don't want my credentials sent in clear text over the Internet WAN. How can I connect to my router publicly using a secure protocol liek HTTPS?

Here is what I have tried:

-checking router (Hitron) for any remote management features so I can configure it to allow browser connections on a different port besides 80. Unfortunately, my router does not have that feature

-forwarding a non-80 port to port 80 of my router internal IP, so I can try connecting to my FQDN on that port and it will direct to 80 once it hits the router. Unfortunately, the router does not let me write a rule that forwards to itself. It does not access localhost or 127.0.0.1 either (says it is in different subnet)

-I thought about using a VPN but I'm cheap and was hoping I could find a free way to do this

Any other thoughts how I can do this?

Comment: Btw, changing port doesn't automatically make it secure/encrypted. tcp 443 != https

Comment: If you can afford a raspberry pi, you can set up a VPN server with it, then with proper routing/masquerading you can access the router's admin page via the tunnel and avoid exposing it to the Internet directly (your router should have an option for that, if not just replace it).

Comment: What model router? It sounds like if you can't flash better firmware to it you won't be able to to modify the router appropriately. A basic pi/VM/PC running OpenBPN as @TomYan suggested is a good idea. I prefer to run dd-wrt (and OpenVPN)

Comment: You wrote "I thought about using a VPN but I'm cheap". You may wish to reconsider. I access my own home system via IPsec VPN and it works just fine